# Compute the 100th Bernstein polynomial for $e^x$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I need to find $$B_3 e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{100} e^{k/100}\binom{100}{k} x^k (1-x)^{100-k}$$

I can rearrange this to find $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{k/100} \left(\frac{100!}{k!(100-k)!}\right) x^k(1-x)^{100-k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\left(e^{k/100} \left(\frac{100!}{(100-k)!}\right)(1-x)^{100-k}\right)$$

I know that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ is the Taylor polynomial of $e^x$ about $0$. I'm supposed to continue to manipulate the series to compute this polynomial, but I'm not sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the binomial theorem:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{100} e^{k/100}\binom{100}{k} x^k (1-x)^{100-k} = (xe^{1/100}+1-x)^{100}.$$